# 1.11 /fill Sticky Piston w/ Direction

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know that 1.11 /fill and /setblock use block data instead of block data. However, when I try to fill an area with sticky pistons facing up, it days that my data values are incorrect. I've tried the following with various capitalizations:

```
/fill x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 sticky_piston {facing:up}
/fill x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 sticky_piston {direction:up}
/fill x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 sticky_piston direction:up
```

From what I've read, {direction:up} or perhaps {Direction:up} should be correct. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Block states should be in the format `variable=value`:

```
/fill x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 sticky_piston facing=up
```

Block states are also still just an alternative to numeric data values. You can use data values if you wish:

```
/fill x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2  sticky_piston 1
```

From the curly brackets (`{`,`}`) and colon (`:`), it looks like you may be getting confused with NBT, which is separate from data values/block states.

Comment: Great! I thought block states behaved similarly to NBT tags.

Answer (score 0):

The way that you would do this would be /fill x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 sticky_piston[facing=up]. Curly brackets and colons aren't for NBT data these days. If you want to learn more about /fill, here is a video that might help you: